# JavaScript - Loop through all HTML elements and select the last one

Tags: javascript, loops

So I'm working on some project where I have multiple elements being created dynamically. One of them is an error log. the whole project is kinda like a command prompt...

If my script returned an error twice (or more) I need to find the last error log and slightly change its number that will indicate how many times the error has repeated...
I Have no idea where to start... Nothing I found on the internet was what was looking for..

Every error log is identical, that's why I can't target them by an id or a class...

```html
<!-- Element structure looks like this: -->
<body>
  <div class='log-container'>
    <!-- Error logs: -->
    <log-elem class='log error'></log-elem>
    <log-elem class='log error'></log-elem>
    <log-elem class='log error'></log-elem>
  </div>
</body>
```

I know I would need a `for` or `while` loop to loop through all the items but that's it...

Please help... And thanks.

Comment: Do you only need to sum up one specific error type at a time, or all error types?

Comment: Just one... I have my own solution for counting errors, the only thing i need is to somehow find the latest error log in the console, and change its counter.

Comment: We need a little more info than that. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Ta.

Comment: If you added a specific class to each error type, you could work by document.getElementByClassname('the_class_name').length(); (to select the last one, assuming you stored the length in a variable called theLength document.getElementByClassname('your_class_name')[theLength-1];

Comment: We need to know what your setup actually looks like. Otherwise all anyone can tell you with any certainty is to grab all the error log elements in an array-like and go to the last index.

Comment: How about [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)?

Comment: `zfrisch agreed.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can find the last `log-elem` and display it:

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('log-elem');
console.log(elems[elems.length-1]);
```

```html
    <!-- Element structure looks like this: -->
    <body>
      <div class='log-container'>
        <!-- Error logs: -->
        <log-elem class='log error'></log-elem>
        <log-elem class='log error'></log-elem>
        <log-elem class='log error'></log-elem>
      </div>
    </body>
```